# Error on retrieving assets for web (flutter)

Tags: image, flutter, assets, flutter-web

I face an issue for Flutter WEB. I followed tutorial on assets from Flutter team (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images) however I receive an error

```
 ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/images/my_custom_image.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart:sdk_internal 4602:11                                  throw_
load
package:flutter_web/…/services/asset_bundle.dart:220
dart:sdk_internal 25309:9                                  <fn>
...

Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/my_custom_image.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#078a9(), name:
  "assets/images/my_custom_image.png", scale: 1)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

My pubspecs.yaml

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

I'm loading image like this

```
Image.asset("assets/images/my_custom_image.png")
```

Where did I mess up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the status of `flutter for web` is still `preview`, assets handling is not the same as for mobile.`assets` folder should be in the `web` folder, and reference path for the image should not include `assets`:

```
Image.asset("images/my_custom_image.png")
```

In `flutter for web`, we do not need to reference the assets in the pubspec.yaml.

Comment: If I move ```assets``` folder under web, pubspec.yaml complains that ```The asset directory assets/images/ does not exist.
Try creating the directory or fixing the path to the directory```

If I keep folder in global path, it doesn't complain

Comment: Got it working. I removed everything from yaml and added path, as you suggested. Thanks @Spatz!

Comment: How would you handle the assets inside a thirdy party package?

Comment: It's totally opposite case in my flutter project. assets/images/some.jpg won't work in local, But on remote it works. Strange path by flutter.