# flutter web app deployed on github.pages cannot access SOME assets

Tags: flutter, github-pages, assets, flutter-web

[UPDATED checkout the issue with steps on [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67655) ]

running my flutter web app locally

`flutter run -d chrome --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true --release`

works as intended ([video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/ancSmzjUmhQATeQZ6)), but building it and deploying it to [github pages](https://pages.github.com/) ([here](https://iapicca.github.io/#/))

`flutter_master build web --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true --release`

doesn't access some asset, but successfully access others.

---

I've tried these solutions ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62466271/9836706), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57738414/9836706))

`'about.json'`  works as expected locally but fails to load when deployed

while `'assets/about.json'` doesn't work in either cases

the code in use can be simplified as

```dart
rootBundle.loadString('about.json');
```

---

I double-checked `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - background_portrait.jpg
    - background_landscape.jpg
    - yf_icon_black.png
    - yf_logo.png
    - about.json
    - apps.json
    - news.json
    - opensource.json
```

and the [assets](https://github.com/iapicca/iapicca.github.io/tree/master/assets) in the build folder

everything checks out, but the issue still persists

in these [logs](https://gist.github.com/iapicca/0c0950ba06dbf62cbf06a44353db06b1) you can see that those files are present

Comment: This is a known issue when that switch/flag is used for building release build. I've read it on one of GitHub issue but can't remember the which one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for me was to eliminate the assets folder completely. I created a folder for each of my asset types in the root dir (same level as lib) and referenced them as directories in pubspec.yaml:

```
  assets:
    - json/
    - avatars/
```

Then when loading them I used a relative path as:

```
await rootBundle.loadString('json/structure.json');
```

Flutter creates an assets folder during build and copies all my asset directories into it. This way it worked for me to load the assets both in debug and in release mode on GitLab Pages.

EDIT: I include the gitlab.ci.yml file I use for gitlab pages build pipeline

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/famedly/containers/flutter-dockerimages:beta
pages:
  script:
    - flutter clean
    - flutter config --enable-web
    - flutter pub get
    - flutter build web --release
    - ls build/web
    - cp -r build/web public
    - ls public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

*The ***ls*** commands you do not need these were just for logging the output during development of the script. I left them there because they do no harm and could come handy sometime.*

Comment: I already use a very similar structure, instead of "json" I called it "data", but otherwise is identical... I have the feeling that build just  does not copy the assets in the build folder...

Comment: you can check that locally with flutter build web --release command, I edited my answer and included the gitlab.ci.yml I use for build

Comment: shouldn't flutter run -d chrome --release provide the same experience of running the deployed version?

Comment: I've updated the question, now it shows the logo, but doesn't load json assets

Comment: glad to hear 

Answer (score 0):

The [official flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images) explains that the assets should be added relative to the path of pubspec.yaml

For your example of `pubspec.yaml`, you should either move the asset files in the root of you project folder or if they are located in an `assets` sub folder add the name of that sub folder in `pubspec.yaml`

E.g. if your files are located under `project_path/assets/`, the assets section of your `pubspec.yaml` should look something like:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/background_portrait.jpg
    - assets/background_landscape.jpg
    - assets/yf_icon_black.png
    - assets/yf_logo.png
    - assets/about.json
    - assets/apps.json
    - assets/news.json
    - assets/opensource.json
```

In your dart code, assets should be accessed by their specified key, for the above example use `'assets/about.json'` and not `'about.json'`

Answer (score 0):

Its an old thread - just in case someone stumbles upon...you have to ensure that a valid certificate is in place. Otherwise the service worker will not start.